# Getting proper query

Tags: mysql

[image: table]

I have this table,
I am trying to get a query to show the zip code one time then have the column headers be the specific animals. I tried using this case query but it did not give me what I wanted (I did a short version so that I wouldn't type it all out while I was testing)

```
select 
  zipcode, 
  case animal when 'dog' then count when 'lizard' then count else 'null' end as animal 
from test1 
order by zipcode;
```

Comment: To help others, maybe you should change the question title to something more descriptive, like 'Converting rows to columns in mysql' or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is the right way to go, but you need aggregation, and many seperate `Case` statements. As written you have a single case statement, which means a single field in your result set.

Instead:

```
select 
  zipcode, 
  Sum(CASE WHEN animal= 'dog' THEN count END) as "Dog",
  SUM(CASE WHEN animal = 'Lizard' THEN count END) as "Lizard",
  etc.. 
from test1 
GROUP BY zipcode
order by zipcode;
```

You'll have to make a `Sum(Case...)` for each animal, so they will each have their own field in your result set. Also, the `GROUP BY` is necessary so that you get a `sum()` over each animal for each zip code.

Comment: This definitely makes sense, but I got an sql syntax error at "from test1"

Comment: And make sure the last field doesn't end with a comma. That will piss off the DB for sure.

Comment: The answer from Michael got me exactly what I wanted after a small change.

Comment: Though I am sure this will work too since CASE and IF are very similar.

Comment: They are pretty much the same. The main different between @Michaels query and mine is the aggregation. His uses MySQL's built in funky GROUP BY handling, where this one is more explicit on how to aggregate the CASE'd fields where it sums the counts for each zip/animal. Often with SQL there are many ways to solve the problem. The fun is figuring out which one is the fastest and cleanest to write.

Comment: @JNevill is right, many roads to Rome, test to find the fastest one. I think JNevill's answer is more complete with the aggregation. The only reason I left that out is after seeing your data, it looked like there would only be one count per animal/zipcode

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this this:

```
select zipcode,
IF (animal='dog', count, 0) as dog,
IF (animal='lizard', count, 0) as lizard
from test1 GROUP by zipcode ORDER by zipcode
```

Comment: I had ot make a change to the code to make it work

'select zipcode,
if (animal = 'dog' count, 0) as dog,
if (animal = 'lizard', count, 0) as lizard
from test1 group by zipcode order by zipcode;